# etree data extraction from xml with odd tree structure

Tags: python, xml, parsing, elementtree

here is a piece of the xml data before i go any further

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xmeml>
<xmeml version="5">
<sequence id="episode1">

    <media>
        <video> 
            <track>

                <generatoritem id="Gen Subtitle1">

                    <effect>
                        <name>Gen Subtitle</name>
                        <effectid>Gen Subtitle</effectid>
                        <effectcategory>Text</effectcategory>
                        <effecttype>generator</effecttype>
                        <mediatype>video</mediatype>
                        <parameter>
                            <parameterid>part1</parameterid>
                            <name>Text Settings</name>
                            <value/>
                        </parameter>
                        <parameter>
                            <parameterid>str</parameterid>
                            <name>Text</name>
                            <value>You're a coward for picking on people&#13;who are weaker than you.</value>
                        </parameter>
                        <parameter>
                            <parameterid>font</parameterid>
                            <name>Font</name>
                            <value>Arial</value>
                        </parameter>

                    </effect>

    </media>
</sequence>
</xmeml>
```

now as you can see the tree starts with `<effect>` and inside there are multiple `<parameters>` but im only ater the `<value>` from `<parameters>` that also contain

```
<parameterid>str</parameterid>
<name>Text</name>
```

so i can get an output of "That child is so cute.And he's smart."

Here is my code

```
lst = tree.findall('xmeml/sequence/media/video/track/generatoritem/effect/parameter/value')
    counts = tree.findall('.//value')

    for each in counts:
        print(each.text)
```

And this is what i get

```
And he's smart.
Arial
```

Comment: start by adding a VALID xml doc to the question body. The current xml is not a valid one

Comment: Im showing a part of the xml because the original one is over 2k lines long

Comment: so create a valid subset of the original.

Comment: i see what you meen thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xmeml>
<xmeml version="5">
<sequence id="episode1">


                    <effect>
                        <name>Gen Subtitle</name>
                        <effectid>Gen Subtitle</effectid>
                        <effectcategory>Text</effectcategory>
                        <effecttype>generator</effecttype>
                        <mediatype>video</mediatype>
                        <parameter>
                            <parameterid>part1</parameterid>
                            <name>Text Settings</name>
                            <value/>
                        </parameter>
                        <parameter>
                            <parameterid>str</parameterid>
                            <name>Text</name>
                            <value>That child is so cute. And he's smart</value>
                        </parameter>
                        <parameter>
                            <parameterid>font</parameterid>
                            <name>Font</name>
                            <value>Arial</value>
                        </parameter>

                    </effect>
</sequence>
</xmeml>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)

str_params = root.findall('.//parameter/[parameterid="str"]')
for param in str_params:
    if param.find('./name').text == 'Text':
        print('The text: {}'.format(param.find('./value').text))
        break
```

output

```
The text: That child is so cute. And he's smart
```

Comment: Very surprised this works since `.//parameter/[parameterid="str"]` isn't a valid XPath.